# Display Data 3 table on mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to ask all my friends for help on my case.

I have several tables that want to connect.

1. customer table

```
   id     | name_cust                         | idmd_pic
-----------------------------+--------------------------
   10     | CF Sukajadi Bandung               | 7
   11     | SPM Toserba Griya Dinasti         | 7
   12     | SPM Toserba Yogya GATSU           | 7
   13     | SPM Toserba Yogya Lucky Square    | 17
   14     | PT Transretail Indonesia/ Sukajadi| 7
```

2. details_the visit table

```
   id     | idcust | name_cust                          | visit_date | idmd_visit
-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
   20     | 12     | SPM Toserba Yogya GATSU            | 2018-03-23 | 7
   21     | 13     | SPM Toserba Yogya Lucky Square     | 2018-03-23 | 17
   22     | 11     | SPM Toserba Griya Dinasti          | 2018-03-23 | 7
   23     | 14     | PT Transretail Indonesia/ Sukajadi | 2018-03-24 | 7
   24     | 11     | SPM Toserba Griya Dinasti          | 2018-03-24 | 7
   25     | 10     | CF Sukajadi Bandung                | 2018-03-24 | 7
   26     | 13     | SPM Toserba Yogya Lucky Square     | 2018-03-24 | 7
   27     | 12     | SPM Toserba Yogya GATSU            | 2018-03-24 | 7
   28     | 11     | SPM Toserba Griya Dinasti          | 2018-03-29 | 17
```

3. datamd table

```
   id     | name_md                           | visit_rotation
-----------------------------+--------------------------
   7      | Nunu Nugraha                      | 9
   17     | Erwin                             | 10
```

I want to generate data like this

```
   id     | name_cust                         | idmd_pic | visit_date | idmd_visit | visit_rotation |
-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
   10     | CF Sukajadi Bandung               | 7        | 2018-03-24 | 7      | 9
   11     | SPM Toserba Griya Dinasti         | 7        | 2018-03-24 | 7      | 9
   12     | SPM Toserba Yogya GATSU           | 7        | 2018-03-24 | 7      | 9
   13     | SPM Toserba Yogya Lucky Square    | 17       | 2018-03-23 | 17     | 10
   14     | PT Transretail Indonesia/ Sukajadi| 7        | 2018-03-24 | 7      | 9
```

Here I am confused how to make the data can be displayed like that, I can not display data in accordance with its idmd_pic and the date of the latest visit, I hope friends here can help, thank you.

Comment: duplicate records of `custID` . which `visit_date` you want means 11 id having 3 records `2018-03-23, 2018-03-24 ,2018-03-29`  so how you decided for `2018-03-24`

Comment: I have changed my question again.

For useless'MJ question, I want to display data according to its idmd PIC even though the customer was visited by other idmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.name_cust,
       c.idmd_pic,
       max(dt.visit_date) as visit_date,
       dt.idmd_visit,
       dm.visit_rotation 
From customer c
inner join details_the dt
on c.id=dt.idcust 
and c.idmd_pic=dt.idmd_visit
inner join datamd dm
on c.idmd_pic=dm.id
GROUP BY C.id
ORDER BY c.id
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a44a42/2

Comment: Try now  @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi

Comment: Welcome @MochamadNurkhayalKadafi